# How to access DataFrame column created with DataFrame.groupby

Tags: python, pandas

After creating a DataFrame with a column 'a' having the duplicated cell values:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                   'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'c':[8,9,10,11,12,13,14]})
```

[image]

I proceed by creating a copy of it where I consolidate the duplicated cells in column 'a' while summing the values of other cells. I am using `groupby` method to achieve this, like so:

```
groupDf = df.groupby('a', axis=0).sum()
```

[image]

After the consolidated version of the DataFrame is created I want to access its columns ['a']:

```
print(groupDf['a])
```

and I am getting the `KeyError` notifying me that ['a'] column does not exist.
Printing the column names with `groupDf.columns` returns only the column 'b' and the column 'c': `Index(['b', 'c'], dtype='object')`

How should I access the column 'a?

Comment: Thanks! It works well. Please post it as a solution so we could vote on your answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the `groupby`, the grouped column turns into an index, you can access it either by call `.index` or `reset_index` and then access it as a normal column, i.e the following two methods:

```
df.groupby('a', axis=0).sum().reset_index()

#   a   b   c
# 0 1   1   8
# 1 2   5   19
# 2 3   22  50

df.groupby('a', axis=0).sum().index
# Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```